# How to deepcopy a function object

Tags: python, deep-copy

I create a function which returns an value specified by an variable. Like

```
y = 1.
def f(x):
    return y
```

I need this function as an function object to create another object

```
dist = dist.distribution(f, other_variables)
```

this works fine. But if i want to create several different distribution objects (with different functions f in the sense that y changes) Like

```
dist = dist.distribution(f, other_variables)
y = 2.
dist2 = dist.distribution(f, other_variables)
```

Then all distribution objects only return the last specified value y. I.e.

```
dist.f()(1.)
>>>> 2.
dist2.f()(1.)
>>>> 2.
```

Instead of the expected

```
dist.f()(1.)
>>>> 12.
dist2.f()(1.)
>>>> 2.
```

The problem clearly is, that the function f accesses the variable only when it is called and not one time initially.

Is there a way around it?
What I want at the end is:
A function with one variable only (x, although this doesnt do anything in this case, it is needed in others), which returns the value of y of the moment, when the distribution is created. So in principle I want that at the initialisation of the distribution, the given function is deepcopyed, in the sense, that it is no longer influenced by any change of variables.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Don't use globals for this. There is no need to 'deepcopy' the function either; the `y` global is not part of the function state *at all*.

Use a function factory that provides a scoped value instead, or use a `functools.partial()` to provide a default argument to your function.

Function factory:

```
def produce_f(y):
    def f(x):
        return y
    return f

dist = dist.distribution(produce_f(1.), other_variables)
```

Now `y` is a scoped value for `f`, `produce_f()` returns a *new* `f` every time it is called, and `y` is stored as a cell variable for `f`.

Demo:

```
>>> f1 = produce_f(12.)
>>> f2 = produce_f(42.)
>>> f1('foo')
12.0
>>> f2('foo')
42.0
```

Using [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

def f(y, x):
    return y

dist = dist.distribution(partial(f, 1.), other_variables)
```

Here `partial(f, 1.)` produces a new callable that will call `f(1., ...)` whenever called, appending any extra arguments passed in.

Demo:

```
>>> f1 = partial(f, 12.)
>>> f2 = partial(f, 42.)
>>> f1('foo')
12.0
>>> f2('foo')
42.0
```

Comment: Cool the partial solution is exactly the answer I searched for...
I tried the $produce_f(y)$ way but it didnt worked out. Maybe I had made a mistake in when exactly y was set and f was produced.
Whaa this press-enter-to-post confuses me, sry for the edits^^

Comment: Nope, not with these techniques it won't.

Comment: Thank you for your promt answer, I'll try it tomorrow